# Change the color of the underline in android

Tags: android, underline

I am developing the android application. I need to underline some of the Textview.

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Ack:");
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
tvAck.setText(content);`
```

I have used the above code for that. But now i want to change the color of the underline. Can any one tell me how to do so. Any help or suggestion is accepted.

Answer (score 15):

There is no documented method to set the underline color. However, there is an undocumented `TextPaint.setUnderline(int, float)` method which allows you do provide the underline color and thickness:

```
final class ColoredUnderlineSpan extends CharacterStyle 
                                 implements UpdateAppearance {
    private final int mColor;

    public ColoredUnderlineSpan(final int color) {
        mColor = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(final TextPaint tp) {
        try {
            final Method method = TextPaint.class.getMethod("setUnderlineText",
                                                            Integer.TYPE,
                                                            Float.TYPE);
            method.invoke(tp, mColor, 1.0f);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            tp.setUnderlineText(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the invocation works but the underline color is still black. :(

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, as a note to others the 1.0f is the line thickness multiplier. A value of 1.0 means default thickness, 2.0 would be twice as thick.

Comment: It works, but the color and thickness are not restored from parcelable (

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this myself, so this is more an idea than a solution, but probably worth trying.  Class `UnderlineSpan` has method `updateDrawState`, which takes `TextPaint` as a parameter.  In turn, TextPain can has field `public int linkColor`.

So for you it would be something like

```
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
tp.linkColor = [your color];           //not quite sure what the format should be
UnderlineSpan us = new UnderlineSpan();
us.updateDrawState(tp);
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Ack:");
content.setSpan(us, 0, content.length(), 0); tvAck.setText(content);
```

Reference for both `TextPaint` and `UnderlineSpan` are very poor, with majority of javadoc missing altogether (judge for yourself: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html), so I'm not certain how to use these though.

Comment: I can't think of anything else.  Why won't it work?  Did you try it?

Comment: The reason that this does not work is that `updateDrawState` only tells the `TextPaint` that it should be underlined. It does not affect the underline color. An `UnderlineSpan` just uses the text color for the underline color. The `linkColor` would change the color of the underline (and text) only for a `ClickableSpan` (or `URLSpan`).

Answer (score 1):

In TextPaint, there has a field 'underlineColor' and method 'setUnderlineText', indicated and can use to changed the underline color. But, they are '@hide' field and method, to use them, you must using reflecting, like this:

```
Field field = TextPaint.class.getDeclaredField("underlineColor");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(ds, mUnderlineColor);
```

ds is your TextPaint Object.

Answer (score 0):

Really late to encounter this scenrio. Here's another way, It would be to set multiple spans to the same spannable content:

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Ack:");
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
content.setSpan(
        new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)),
        0,
        content.length(),
        0
);
tvAck.setText(content, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Its change text color with underline.... not just underline