# How to set color of UnderlineSpan?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

This question is a follow up to my last question: [How to highlight text like Android spell-checker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530546/how-to-highlight-text-like-android-spell-checker)

I'm using an UnderlineSpan to underline text in an EditText but I need the underline to be **IN COLOR** like this screen shot of the spelling checker:

[image]

Comment: This is probably the best you'll do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684560/change-the-color-of-the-underline-in-android ... Or, perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238298/android-change-underline-color-from-an-edittext-dynamically

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately the first solution didn't work (both answers) and I cannot use the second since my app is a keyboard, which  cannot access the EditText directly.

Comment: The problem is that there is no API-supported method to do it, at least not on stock Android.

Comment: The only way I could find was to use a SuggestionSpan, which can be red, blue or light gray, but not any custom color.

Comment: Check the @android-developer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665758/2713403

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't do this solely with a Span -- there are no public methods to do what you ask.  There is a method to set the underline color in TextPaint independent of the text color (you can see it in the source code for SuggestionSpan) but [it's hidden](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/TextPaint.java#38).

If you can get access to the EditText, you can handle the Span and draw the underline yourself, but otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

here is the function which you can use to set color of line below text

```
public void addUnderLineLink(TextView mTextView) {
    if (mTextView != null) {
        SpannableString content = new SpannableString(mTextView.getText().toString());
        UnderlineSpan us=new UnderlineSpan();
        TextPaint tp=new TextPaint();
        tp.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.white));
        us.updateDrawState(tp);
        content.setSpan(us, 0, mTextView.getText().toString().length(), 0);
        mTextView.setText(content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Android 10 (SDK 29) you can do this by setting `underlineColor` and `underlineThickness` of `TextPaint`.

Example:

```
val text = SpannableString("Your string")
text.setSpan(ColoredUnderlineSpan(Color.RED, 10f), 0, 4, SpannableString.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
textView.text = text

class ColoredUnderlineSpan constructor(
    @ColorInt private val underlineColor: Int,
    private val underlineThickness: Float,
) : CharacterStyle() {
    override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
        textPaint.underlineColor = underlineColor
        textPaint.underlineThickness = underlineThickness
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i made it work

```
Spanned part_1 = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.part1));
Spanned part_2 = Html.fromHtml("<u><font color='#2eb6f0'>Text in blue</font></u>");
Spanned part_3 = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.part3));
Spanned output = (Spanned) TextUtils.concat(part_1, part_2, part_3);

textview.setText(output, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```