# How to underline text in TextView with some different color than that of text?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I know how to underline text in a textview. But how to underline text with some different color ?
Underline can be done with:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
t.setText("Underline Text");
```

Let say my textcolor is black and I want to underline the same with blue color, how to do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am afraid you need two textviews for that!

Comment: You can use like this
Email.setText(Html.fromHtml("W : "+"<u><FONT COLOR=\"#80776b\" >"+Email1+"</Font></u>"));
 Use color code what you want.

Comment: ~Vipul J, did you overcome this problem?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem and I have stumbled upon [Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) class when reading some other posts for doing this on `EditText`. It provides everything you need to make this happen by manually drawing underline with canvas.

First I defined custom attributes for an easy customization in XML layout files

```
<declare-styleable name="UnderlinedTextView" >
    <attr name="underlineHeight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="underlineOffset" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="underlineColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="underLinePosition" format="enum">
        <enum name="baseline" value="0" />
        <enum name="below" value="1" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

And a custom `TextView` class

```
   class UnderlinedTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
    @IntDef(POSITION_BASELINE, POSITION_BELOW)
    annotation class UnderLinePosition {
        companion object {
            const val POSITION_BASELINE = 0
            const val POSITION_BELOW = 1
        }
    }

    private val linePaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    var lineColor: Int
        get() = linePaint.color
        set(value) {
            if (linePaint.color != value) {
                linePaint.color = value
                invalidate()
            }
        }

    var lineHeight: Float
        get() = linePaint.strokeWidth
        set(value) {
            if (linePaint.strokeWidth != value) {
                linePaint.strokeWidth = value
                updateSpacing()
            }
        }

    var lineTopOffset = 0F
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                field = value
                updateSpacing()
            }
        }

    @UnderLinePosition
    var linePosition = POSITION_BASELINE

    private val rect = Rect()

    private var internalAdd: Float = lineSpacingExtra

    private inline val extraSpace
        get() = lineTopOffset + lineHeight

    init {
        val density = context.resources.displayMetrics.density

        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView, defStyleAttr, 0)
        lineColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView_underlineColor, currentTextColor)
        lineTopOffset = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView_underlineOffset, 0f)
        lineHeight = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView_underlineHeight, density * 1)
        linePosition = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView_underLinePosition, POSITION_BASELINE)
        typedArray.recycle()
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight + (extraSpace + 0.5f).toInt())
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.takeIf { !text.isNullOrEmpty() }?.let {
            val count = lineCount
            val layout = layout
            var xStart: Float
            var xStop: Float
            var yStart: Float
            var firstCharInLine: Int
            var lastCharInLine: Int
            var lastLine: Boolean
            var offset: Int
            val lineSpacing = lineSpacingExtra * lineSpacingMultiplier
            for (i in 0 until count) {
                val baseline = getLineBounds(i, rect)
                lastLine = i == count - 1
                offset = if (lastLine) 0 else 1
                firstCharInLine = layout.getLineStart(i)
                lastCharInLine = layout.getLineEnd(i)
                xStart = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(firstCharInLine)
                xStop = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(lastCharInLine - offset)
                yStart = when (linePosition) {
                    POSITION_BASELINE -> baseline + lineTopOffset
                    POSITION_BELOW -> (rect.bottom + lineTopOffset) - if (lastLine) 0F else lineSpacing
                    else -> throw NotImplementedError("")
                }
                canvas.drawRect(xStart, yStart, xStop, yStart + lineHeight, linePaint)
            }
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }

    private fun updateSpacing() {
        setLineSpacing(internalAdd, 1f)
    }

    override fun setLineSpacing(add: Float, mult: Float) {
        internalAdd = add
        super.setLineSpacing(add + extraSpace, 1f)
    }
}
```

Then it's usage is simple

```
<some.package.UnderlinedTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This is a demo text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:underlineColor="#ffc112ef"
    app:underlineHeight="3dp"/>
```

**Final result**

- Multi line 
  [image]
- Single line 
  [image]

Comment: how can i underline only a specific text with this custom view, without spannable and else....

Comment: I think you have a crash on this `UnderlinedTextView` class, in case the text is empty. As a workaround, I think it's fine to add a check about the text on `onDraw` :        `if (text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            super.onDraw(canvas)
            return
        }`

Comment: Saved my a** when our designer gave me some custom fonts that would only render an extremely thin line when using an UnderlineSpan. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, this time without extending TextView (based on a question I wrote a long time ago, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43518126/878126)) :

Have a drawable to be shown as the underline, and have a span for the text itself :

**text_underline.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <padding android:bottom="10dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#3792e5"/>
</shape>
```

**DrawableSpan.kt**

```
class DrawableSpan(private val drawable: Drawable) : ReplacementSpan() {
    private val padding: Rect = Rect()

    init {
        drawable.getPadding(padding)
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int, paint: Paint) {
        val rect = RectF(x, top.toFloat(), x + measureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom.toFloat())
        drawable.setBounds(rect.left.toInt() - padding.left, rect.top.toInt() - padding.top, rect.right.toInt() + padding.right, rect.bottom.toInt() + padding.bottom)
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y.toFloat(), paint)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
    }

    override fun getSize(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?): Int = Math.round(paint.measureText(text, start, end))

    private fun measureText(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int): Float = paint.measureText(text, start, end)

}
```

usage:

```
    val text = getString(R.string.large_text)
    val spannable = SpannableString(text)
    spannable.setSpan(DrawableSpan(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_underline)), 0, text.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    textView.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are an XML's fan. Take a look at my solution:

Create a selector `selector_edittext_white.xml` in drawable folder

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:bottom="-15dp">
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="0.5"
        android:pivotY="0.5"
        android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then, set your EditText

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext_white"
```

In the setting above, the underline's color is **white**, and you can move it by changing `android:bottom` above is "-15dp" . In case it's disappear, try to set your EditText bottom margin like this

```
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

Comment: This is a quite nice solution for single-lined text, but it does not work if the text is multi-lined.

Comment: Nice solution for a single line text. Used in android.widget.Button, it doesn't work in material buttons...

Answer (score 4):

I can't add a comment yet, so I'm posting as an answer instead.

I just want to say that Bojan Kseneman's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30717100/2771087) is fantastic. There's one issue with it that I'd like to correct, though.

Rather than finding the end position of the last character in a line, it's grabbing the end of second last character and then adding the width of the first character in the line. These two lines here:

```
x_diff = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(firstCharInLine + 1) - x_start;
x_stop = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(lastCharInLine - 1) + x_diff;
```

Instead of this, getSecondaryHorizontal() can be used to grab the opposite side of the character, as in:

```
x_stop = layout.getSecondaryHorizontal(lastCharInLine);
```

However, this will also underline the space at the end of each line for multi-line text areas. So to fix that issue, use code like the following to skip past it before calculating x_stop:

```
while (lastCharInLine != firstCharInLine &&
       Character.isWhitespace(getText().charAt(lastCharInLine - 1))) {
    lastCharInLine--;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Not so "stubby" after all!

Answer (score 4):

```
imee.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#9e4c4e>  <u>" + ime + "</u>  </font>"));
avtorr.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#90494f>  <u>" + avtorr + "</u>  </font>"));
```

The best solution is with using Html.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, also with span

**ColoredUnderlineSpan.kt**

```
/**
 * A span which draw a colored line below the text
 *
 * @property color The color of the underline
 * @property thickness The thickness of the line in pixels
 */
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
class ColoredUnderlineSpan(@ColorInt private val color: Int, @Px private val thickness: Float) : CharacterStyle(), UpdateAppearance {
    override fun updateDrawState(tp: TextPaint) {
        tp.underlineColor = color
        tp.underlineThickness = thickness
    }
}

/**
 * A span which draw a colored line below the text
 *
 * @param color The color of the underline
 * @property thickness The thickness of the line in pixels
 */
class ColoredUnderlineSpanPreQ(@ColorInt color: Int, @Px private val thickness: Float) : ReplacementSpan() {

    private val linePaint = Paint().apply {
        this.color = color
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int, paint: Paint) {
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(x, bottom - thickness, (x + paint.measureText(text, start, end)), bottom.toFloat(), linePaint)
    }

    override fun getSize(
        paint: Paint,
        text: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?
    ): Int = paint.measureText(text, start, end).roundToInt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me:

```
terms.setText(Html.fromHtml("I have read and agree to the <u><font color='red'>Terms and Conditions</u>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it one line (short) text it is possible to solve it very easy way in XML file
This example is grey text with orange underline on white background

```xml
{
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textUnderLineLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_orange">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/underlined_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:text="@string/some_text_string"
                android:textColor="@color/color_grey"
                android:background="@color/color_white"/>
    </LinearLayout>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this [android developer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665758/3998710), I come up with another solution, for better understanding the bounds and position of the underline.

**text_underline.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="1dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!--<corners android:radius="2dp" /> -->
            <solid android:color="#D9FFFFFF" />
            <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**usage** in TextView or Button:

```
SpannableString(text).apply {
    setSpan(object : ReplacementSpan() {
        @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
        private val drawable: Drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_underline, null)

        override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int, paint: Paint) {
            drawable.setBounds(x.toInt(),
                top,
                (x + measureText(paint, text, start, end)).toInt(),
                (bottom + (buttonHeight - (bottom - top)) / 2.0f).roundToInt())

            canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y.toFloat(), paint)
            drawable.draw(canvas)
        }

        override fun getSize(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?): Int =
            paint.measureText(text, start, end).roundToInt()

        private fun measureText(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int): Float = paint.measureText(text, start, end)

    },
        0,
        text.length,
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    setText(this, BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```

`buttonHeight` is the height of the View you want to apply the underline style to.

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    t.setPaintFlags(p.getColor());
    t.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    t.setText("Underline Text");
```

make a new paint color. and assign the paint to the textview.

Comment: **Color.RED** is for choosing the paint's color.

Comment: and tell me what u get/see

Comment: Still not working, "UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG" is a static field, so it doesn't matter what 'p' is.

Comment: it's a warning. When u run ur app, what do u see/ happens ?

Comment: Nothing, underlines with same color as before. 
And that warning means it won't work.