# Changing the underline color of TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to change the color of the underline indicator in a `TextView`.

I know I can underline text like this

```
Spanned htmlString = Html.fromHtml("<u> <font color=\"#FF0000\"> some text </font> </u>")
someTextView.setText(htmlString);
```

And like this

```
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(test);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, test.length(), 0);
tvTest.setText(content);
```

But both solutions use the same color for the text and the underline indicator. I want to know if I can change the color of the underline indicator in a sane way without any background XML and reflection hacks as seen here

- [How to underline text in TextView with some different color than that of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046614/how-to-underline-text-in-textview-with-some-different-color-than-that-of-text)

I want to underline only the text, not the paddings, margins. My text can span over multiple lines too, I want every line to be underlined. (This is where the XML solution fails).

Result of my code
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It feels weird answering my own question, but for the sake of anyone having the same problem, I will. I have stumbled upon [Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) class when reading some other posts for doing this on `EditText`. It provides everything you need to make this happen by manually drawing underline with canvas.

First I defined custom attributes for an easy customization in XML layout files

```
<declare-styleable name="UnderlinedTextView" >
    <attr name="underlineWidth" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="underlineColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And a custom `TextView` class

```
public class UnderlinedTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private Rect lineBoundsRect;
    private Paint underlinePaint;

    public UnderlinedTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public UnderlinedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public UnderlinedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {

        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView, defStyle, 0);
        int mColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView_underlineColor, 0xFFFF0000);
        float mStrokeWidth = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.UnderlinedTextView_underlineWidth, density * 2);
        typedArray.recycle();

        lineBoundsRect = new Rect();
        underlinePaint = new Paint();
        underlinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        underlinePaint.setColor(mColor); //color of the underline
        underlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
    }

    @ColorInt
    public int getUnderLineColor() {
        return underlinePaint.getColor();
    }

    public void setUnderLineColor(@ColorInt int mColor) {
        underlinePaint.setColor(mColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getUnderlineWidth() {
       underlinePaint.getStrokeWidth()
    }

    public void setUnderlineWidth(float mStrokeWidth) {
        underlinePaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int count = getLineCount();

        final Layout layout = getLayout();
        float x_start, x_stop, x_diff;
        int firstCharInLine, lastCharInLine;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int baseline = getLineBounds(i, lineBoundsRect);
            firstCharInLine = layout.getLineStart(i);
            lastCharInLine = layout.getLineEnd(i);

            x_start = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(firstCharInLine);
            x_diff = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(firstCharInLine + 1) - x_start;
            x_stop = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(lastCharInLine - 1) + x_diff;

            canvas.drawLine(x_start, baseline + mStrokeWidth, x_stop, baseline + mStrokeWidth, underlinePaint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Then it's usage is simple

```
<some.package.UnderlinedTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This is a demo text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:underlineColor="#ffc112ef"
    app:underlineWidth="3dp"/>
```

**Final result**

- Multi line 
  [image]
- Single line 
  [image]

Comment: Really nice method, congrats! Though I have a problem when using it, line don't always align the same way: sometimes they end before the word, sometimes a bit after. I don't know if it might be a problem with padding or something. Do you know why this could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: @BojanKseneman, how can i underline only a specific text with this custom view, without spannable and else...

Comment: @BojanKseneman Great answer buddy, Just one problem:
How to increase gap between underline and text as it is looks too close ?

Comment: I found my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47461749/1384010 
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: this is working code i am tested this code is any one extract the any problem ths used this code