# Underline text in Xamarin.Android witn MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin.android, textview, mvvmcross

I have `Xamarin.Android project` and use `MVVMCross`. I need to add some underlining text in my `.axml` layout.

I found some ways to do it but its don't work for me.

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    local:MvxBind="Text Strings[Text01]" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLink"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#1565C0"
    android:layout_below="@id/TextView01"
    local:MvxBind="Text Strings[textLink]; Click MyCommand" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

1. The string.

   ```
   <string name="your_string"><u>Underlined text</u></string>
   ```

I can't use this way because I use two languages and I have the folder `Locales` with two `.txt` files. So the project doesn't take strings from `strings.xml`

2. Paint.

   ```
       TextView MyLink = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MyLink);
       MyLink.PaintFlags = (MyLink.PaintFlags | Android.Graphics.PaintFlags.UnderlineText);
   ```
3. FromHtml.

   ```
   txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>underlined</u> text"));
   ```

Doesn't work for me, besides I see the green underline and comment that this decision is deprecated.

How can I mark my `TextView` as underlined?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046614/how-to-underline-text-in-textview-with-some-different-color-than-that-of-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 looks like Java instead of xamarin c#, try:

```
txtView.PaintFlags = (txtView.PaintFlags | Android.Graphics.PaintFlags.UnderlineText);
```

And use the correct Id.

Answer (score 1):

Create own textView and use it instead of standart textView in axml

```
public class UnderlineTextView : TextView

private void Initialize()
{
    //this.PaintFlags = this.PaintFlags | Android.Graphics.PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
    //this.Text = "This text will be underlined";

    String underlineData = this.Text;
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(underlineData);
    content.SetSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, underlineData.Length, 0);
    // 0 specify start index and underlineData.length() specify end index of styling
    this.TextFormatted = content;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it. I created the `UnderlineTextView.cs` inside `Helpers`. But I have underlined `UnderlineTextView` with the error: `CS1729 'TextView' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

Comment: When you inherit you need also inherit constructors from textView!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `txtView.TextFormatted = Html.fromHtml("<u>underlined</u> text");` for it to work as you're expecting.

It's often ideal to use data binding when you're using the MVVM pattern. An approach using data binding with MvvmCross is to use a [ValueConverter](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters) that accepts string input and outputs a `SpannableString` which you can use with the `TextFormatted` MvvmCross binding.

```
public class UnderlinedStringValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, SpannableString>
{
    protected override SpannableString Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var spannable = new SpannableString(value ?? string.Empty);
        spannable.SetSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spannable.Length(), 0);
        return spannable;
    }
}
```

Then in your `TextView` AXML:

```
<TextView
  ....
  local:MvxBind="TextFormatted UnderlinedString(Strings[textLink]);" />
```