# How do I create this small custom bottom underline view with only one side and short length?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-drawable

I am trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TVGm.jpg) one custom underline for text-view so far I have reached very close, need help just to get it right.

I have tried to implement custom stroke in `layer-list` drawable then with the help of another `layer-list`, I added the `inset` tag and added the left and right parameter but couldn't hide either one. Please Help me out.

[just_bottom_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFJxC.jpg)

[so_far_reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuYs2.jpg)

**custom_underline_text.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Custom text underline-->
    <item android:top="-3dp" android:left="-3dp" android:right="-3dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/mt_color_blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**shrink_left_right.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <inset android:drawable="@drawable/custom_underline_text"
               android:insetLeft="180dp" android:insetRight="180dp"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I use this custom underline property in a style so that I can change programmatically on run time.

**styles.xml**

```xml
<style name="Custom_text_select">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_underline_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">4dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Why don't you use **[UnderlineSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan)**

Comment: Can I get the same behaviour with Underline Span? @NileshRathod

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30717100/7666442

Comment: Ok I got your point about underline span there is stroke width size but what about the length of the underline, can you suggest something for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Drawable like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <size android:height="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/divider" />

</shape>
```

and set is as drawableBottom in your TextView

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this thing didn't work out it changes the whole background